# Compute difference between current and previous doc in ElasticSearch Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, sum, aggregation

I have and index which stores measures with following structure:

```
{sensorId: 'sensor1', value: '13.5', 'timestamp': '2016-02-19 12:00:00'}
{sensorId: 'sensor1', value: '15.7', 'timestamp': '2016-02-19 12:02:00'}
{sensorId: 'sensor1', value: '14.3', 'timestamp': '2016-02-19 12:09:00'}
{sensorId: 'sensor1', value: '14.6', 'timestamp': '2016-02-19 12:13:00'}
```

Is there any way to aggregate these measures and return the sum of the difference between a measure and the previous measure? For example the operation should be similar to this:

```
"query" : {
   //operations
 },
  "aggs": {
    "difference_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "difference": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "doc[index]['value'].value - doc[index-1]['value'].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you feed your data into ES? Via Logstash?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Nope. Could you solve it?

Comment: @Sapikelio did you solve it?

Comment: @JosepB Nop. Sorry

Comment: Please check this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/52918157/3838328  The solution I've mentioned in there is similar to what the requirement is. Basically I have implemented the `serial difference aggregation` feature of Elasticsearch. You can find more on this in this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-serialdiff-aggregation.html Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to take a quick look ;)