# Compute difference in data_histogram aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a collection of customers I want to analyze. I am interested in customer growth, e.g.:

- +43 (+32%) new customers since last week
- +12650 (+1140%) new customers since last year

What to do:

- get customers that where created this week
- get customers that where created last week
- count them
- compute difference (in percentage)

So first I would create a histogram to bucket the customers by week:

```
{  
  "aggs":{  
    "customers_over_time":{  
      "date_histogram":{  
        "field":"created",
        "interval":"week"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This e.g. results in

```
{  
  "buckets":[  
    ...,
    {  
      "key_as_string":"2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "key":1538352000000,
      "doc_count":1
    },
    {  
      "key_as_string":"2018-10-08T00:00:00.000Z",
      "key":1538956800000,
      "doc_count":7
    },
    {  
      "key_as_string":"2018-10-15T00:00:00.000Z",
      "key":1539561600000,
      "doc_count":5
    }
  ]
}
```

I would then just take the last two entries and compute the difference, and assign it to a field, outside of the buckets collection. Is that possible in elasticsearch, maybe through *Bucket Script Aggregation*?

Another thought was to do some optimization and create the histogram only for a limited number of customers. I tried:

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "range":{  
      "created":{  
        "gte":"now-1w",
        "lte":"now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However this does not take into account the entire last week but just the last 7 days, which is not the same as last week. Is there a way to have customers created this week and last week?

Comment: You could possibly use a range query with scripted metric aggregation to do it for specific time period. Could also add a field or two that hold the week of the year and the year to the existing docs and do it with a simple aggregation then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've tried something and I hope it would be useful. I've made use of  the **Serial Difference Aggregation** feature of `Elasticsearch` and you can refer to this [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-serialdiff-aggregation.html) for more details.

Let's say I have `three` documents for this week i.e `week starting from 2018-10-15` and only `one` document for last week i.e `week starting from 2018-10-08`

Difference of users created during the week `2018-10-15` would be `2`

Below is the sample query I've come up with which would show you the difference of the count from the previous week.

### Query

```
POST testdateindex/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "range" : {
          "created" : {
            "from":"now-2w",
            "to":"now",
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "customers_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created",
        "interval": "week"
      },
      "aggs": {
            "difference": {
               "serial_diff": {                
                  "buckets_path": "_count",
                  "lag" : 1
               }
            }
         }
    }
  }
}
```

I've used the `lag` as `1` as you only require difference between two consecutive weeks or buckets in this case.

### Query Result:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "customers_over_time": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2018-10-08T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1538956800000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2018-10-15T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1539561600000,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "difference": {
            "value": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The result would display count of all documents for that week along with the `difference` part in the above json which would hold the difference in count to that of last week.

Note that the first bucket doesn't have `difference` because I haven't created any document prior to that week.

Hope it helps!

Comment: any luck with the above? does it help?